# Why did Jesus not share the meanings of the parables? MARK 4:34

Tags: exegesis, christology, gospel-of-mark, parables

In Mark 4:34 it says:

> "He did not say anything to them without using a parable. But when He was alone with his own disciples, he explained everything." (NIV)

My question is this: why did Jesus not share the meanings of the parables with the general population he talked to and only to his disciples?

Comment: I moved the question to the title. But the edit is under review. Like that it is more obvious that the question is not a duplicate. I think the word "secrecy" triggered their duplicate alarm.

Comment: @Hjan A question similar to the new title of this onehas also been asked previously; I've added a link to it above.

Comment: @Nathaniel, yes that one is really similar, i agree on that.  Thanks for taking my comment in to consideration.